# Are there any hints in the CMB as to why the James Webb telescope is finding galaxies larger than expected in the early universe?

Tags: galaxy, cosmic-microwave-background, james-webb-space-telescope

"James Webb telescope detects evidence of ancient ‘universe breaker’ galaxies | Astronomy | The Guardian" https://amp.theguardian.com/science/2023/feb/22/universe-breakers-james-webb-telescope-detects-six-ancient-galaxies

"First images from Nasa’s James Webb space telescope reveal ancient galaxies | James Webb space telescope | The Guardian" https://www.theguardian.com/science/2022/jul/11/nasa-james-webb-telescope-ancient-galaxy-images

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what sorts of hint you'd expect, or why you'd expect any hints in the CMB?

Comment: @pela Perhaps an anomalously high  redshift in the cmb for this region of space where there was a higher density of matter than usual  or perhaps a CMB in this region with a lower or higher standard 
 deviation than usual. Or even with a more symmetrical statistical distribution.

Comment: The CMB originates from regions that are many billions of lightyears more distant than any galaxy, so they aren't really correlated (except for the [SZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunyaev–Zeldovich_effect)/[SW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachs–Wolfe_effect) effects where later _clusters_ of galaxies leave an imprint in the CMB). Although it's not impossible that the concordance model of the Universe, ΛCDM, is wrong, I can give you a long list of reasons why the JWST galaxies might not have broken ΛCDM just yet.